# Registering default route in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, start-page

I have a ASP .NET 4.5 app that includes WebForms, MVC and Web API. Registering a default route worked fine as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute
(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Signin" }
);
```

I then set an ASPX page as the project start page for testing and could not figure out how to revert that change. The routes are still in place but not working.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Please right click on project -> select Properties and select option base on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the project, go to Properties -> Web.  Choose a different Start Action.